# How to install Midori browser on Ubuntu using PPA?

Tags: software-installation

How to install **Midori** browser from PPA on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: 1st one i got though google:`midori ppa`

Comment: @Sneetsher if you're not going to post a useful answer, don't post anything at all.

Comment: @pzkpfw, This question does not show any [search efforts](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). I down voted it & commented. I don't remember if it was in the review queue.

Comment: "How to ask" is there to help people, not as a rule to reference when you feel like being rude. See ["be nice"](https://askubuntu.com/help/be-nice), specifically #2.

Comment: @pzkpfw, even #1 applies here, thank you I will keep it in mind and try to avoid such behavior . Sorry k.p .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the following commands,

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:midori/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install midori
```

Comment: I get `E: Package 'midori' has no installation candidate` when last line is run. Any fix to that? on Lubuntu 17.10

Comment: @Nae Perhaps here: https://askubuntu.com/a/989052/57576