# How to install Midori?

Tags: apt, software-installation, lubuntu, 17.10, midori

I tried to install [midori](http://midori-browser.org/) using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/676535/634142):

> Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> and run the following
>   commands,
>
> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:midori/ppa
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install midori
> ```

but I got following error:

```
E: Package 'midori' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: I think he means https://launchpad.net/~midori/+archive/ubuntu/ppa If you really want to give it a shot I guess the only option would be instead download the `.deb` file from [here](http://midori-browser.org/download/ubuntu/) and install it e.g using `gdebi <.deb file>` or `dpkg -i <.deb file>`

Comment: You may try to install midori [from 17.04](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/zesty/universe/base/midori), but it is not good idea. You may want to try other lightweight browsers such as `surf`, `netsurf`, `arora`, `rekonq`, `qupzilla`, `epiphany-browser`. Or `chromium`.

Comment: Again, it is NOT recommended. However, If you  *really* want to, you can edit the ppa file to install. If you are interested, please let me know and I will post an answer but it doesn't always work because of dependencies.

Comment: The midori PPA has not been updated since 2015-08-30, but a new version is released (announced Nov 30 2018) and is available as snap and tarball. See the answer by @ DK Bose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to install midori by compiling its source code under Ubuntu 17.10. Be aware though that there has been *no development* of this browser for some time so various security concerns will not have been addressed.

Just 4 simple steps are required:

**1. Download build tools and dev files:**

You will need a set of compiling tools and some 'development' files to build midori. Simply copy the  following *single command* into a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake valac libvala-0.36-dev \
libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev libsqlite3-dev libsoup-gnome2.4-dev libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev \
libzeitgeist-2.0-dev libgcr-3-dev librsvg2-bin intltool
```

**2.Create a build directory & download the source:**

Next create a build directory and download and extract the midori source here. Again the following is a *single command:*

```
mkdir $HOME/midori_build && cd $HOME/midori_build && \
wget http://midori-browser.org/downloads/midori_0.5.11_all_.tar.bz2 && \
tar xvf midori_0.5.11_all_.tar.bz2
```

**3. Alter the source:**

midori requires some tweaking to compile with newer libraries and the following snippet borrows from [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/stable-systemd/xsoft/midori.html) to achieve this. Again a *single command*:

```
cd $HOME/midori_build/midori-0.5.11 && \
sed -e 's/protected Tally/public Tally/g' -i midori/midori-notebook.vala && \
sed -e 's/%d other files/%u other files/g' -i extensions/transfers.vala && \
for f in transfers adblock/widgets apps history-list notes; do
    sed -e 's/.remove (iter/.remove (ref iter/g' -i "extensions/$f.vala"
done
```

**4. Compile and install midori:**

Use the following *single command* to now compile and install midori (packaged with checkinstall for easy removal):

```
cd $HOME/midori_build/midori-0.5.11 && \
mkdir build && cd build && \
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
      -DUSE_GTK3=ON \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DHALF_BRO_INCOM_WEBKIT2=ON .. && make && \
sudo checkinstall -D --install=yes --fstrans=no --pakdir "$HOME/midori_build" \
   --pkgname midori --backup=no --deldoc=yes --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --default \
   --pkgversion "0.5.11" && \
sudo ldconfig
```

**Screenshot:**

Below is a screenshot of the completed installation on my 17.10 system. Note that there is still a little remedial work needed for the sidebar (dock) icon but I will investigate after Xmas :).

[image]

**References:**

- [Linux From Scratch: midori](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/stable-systemd/xsoft/midori.html) Patching information from here so that midori will compile against recent vala

Answer (score 4):

Midori seems to be actively developed again.
• https://www.midori-browser.org/2018/11/30/lorem-ipsum/
• https://github.com/midori-browser/core/releases/.

Some features of Midori 7:
• Fixed YouTube rendering issue due to custom user agent
• Fixed invisible cursor in text fields
• Restored behavior of " " and "." in urlbar completion
• Download/ web notifications for background window/ tab
• Highlight in toolbar for finished downloads
• Re-introduced proxy server UX
• Multiple processes for indivdual tabs
• Adaptive toolbar layout for smaller screens

It's available as [a snap](https://snapcraft.io/midori) or as [a tar](https://github.com/midori-browser/core/releases/download/v7/midori-v7.0.tar.gz).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way now is to use the snap package.

In terminal type -

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install midori
```

Comment: Unfortunately Snap version of Midori is no longer updated. Current version is 1.1.4 from 30 September 2020 (6 months ago) as available on https://astian.org/en/midori-browser/download/ while the Snap version is still from old stream v8.0-31

Comment: Even Flathub was not updated for some time. Aparently packages available on the website are the only option